# I have a very long photo and I want to download it in Unity I get this error : ( Texture has out of range width / height ) what can i do

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, download, size

I have a very long photo and I want to download it in Unity I get this error : ( Texture has out of range width / height ) what can i do

This is the picture : https://team1x1.com/wp-content/uploads/TeamX-upload/manga_5fddfe622f64e/5fddfe6239587/1/002.jpg

I downloaded the image and then saved it to the files and when it was called to the scene I get this error :

Texture has out of range width / height
UnityEngine.ImageConversion:LoadImage (UnityEngine.Texture2D,byte[])

```
        byte[] fileData;
        fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        texture = new Texture2D(32, 32);
        texture.LoadImage(fileData); //At this line the error comes
```

Give me your opinion on how to overcome this problem ؟؟

Comment: By the way, the short images are free of problems

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in larger numbers into the new Texture2D(#,#); function. Its likely that the large image doesnt fit within a 32x32  2D texture, hence the error message "Texture has out of range width / height"

Try 64x64, or whatever the height/width for the large image is. The google chrome HTML inspector says that image is width = 57 and height = 969. both 57, and 969 are larger than 32, so  a new Texture2D(32,32) will not fit.

Edit #1: Upon further research, it appears that your image may be too big for your format / gpu :

User Aras says " Yeah, today we clamp max Texture2D sizes to 16384. Since that's a common "max supported limit" on many GPUs & graphics APIs."
https://forum.unity.com/threads/texture2d-has-out-of-range-width.501936/

The unity docs have this desclaimer: Note that not all graphics cards support all texture formats, use SystemInfo.SupportsTextureFormat to check. Also, only the Texture2D class supports texture creation from script with Crunch compression texture formats.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.html

Comment: I've tried to do that but to no avail, The purpose of setting the height and width from "Texture2D(32,32)" is just to create "Texture2D" meaning there is another code to modify the height, width and color of the image but the image must be imported through "texture.LoadImage(fileData);" And here is the error

Comment: Have you tried passing in 57 and 969 or larger numbers? 

What line is that error thrown on? the constructor call, or the LoadImage(filedata); line? Is LoadImage() actually called?

Comment: according to this, https://forum.unity.com/threads/texture2d-has-out-of-range-width.501936/ your image is likely just too big,  User Aras says " Yeah, today we clamp max Texture2D sizes to 16384. Since that's a common "max supported limit" on many GPUs & graphics APIs."

Comment: Yes my friend I tried to pass a lot of big numbers, But the problem most likely lies in the large number of beyts for the image, This is a picture of the complete error Img : https://j.top4top.io/p_2070fnwhl1.png

Comment: Hmmm, well, do you have any suggestion to add this picture, even if we divided it into more than one section and presented it to more than one Texture2d??

Comment: That doesn't matter at all you can use `new Texture(1,1)` and still load in larger images .. the dimensions are overwritten by whatever dimensions the loaded image has